# My AzureWeb job ignore CRON expression and always run

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I everyone,
I have created a azure web job that should run daily every 5 minutes between 06.00am and 10pm.

This is the CRON expression I have used `0 0/5 6-10 * * *`.

But for some reason the job run continuously, in the night too. 
The app service under the web job runs has the `Always on` set on `On`.

Here the code of my job:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyEngine myEngine = new MyEngine();
    myEngine.Run();
}
```

`myEngine.Run()` run the following code:

```
Threading.Task.Run(() =>
{
    this.processTaskActivities();
}, this.cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

I do not think this is the correct approach to run a web job, but I cannot change it...

Why my webjob run alway?

Thank you

**EDIT**
I let you see how the job is configured:

[image]

PS.: The CRON expression is just to text according the time. To understand if it stops and if it runs when necessary

Comment: the cron expression is incorrect. every 5 minutes between 6 am and 10 pm should be: `0 */5 6-22 * * *` , please take a try.

Comment: I have added this CRON to test `0 */5 4 * * *` but the job still seems to run continously

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file called `settings.job` along with your project and while deploying it will automatically detect the cron expression

**settings.job**

```
{"schedule": "0 0/5 6-10 * * *"}
```

Follow this [Article](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs/#.W79ZWGgzaUk)

Comment: I already had that file and I was already modifying it. But no success

Comment: Are you sure your WebJob is deployed as a Triggered WebJob and not Continuous?

Comment: @DavidEbbo Yes... I have checked.. it is triggered and near I can see the CRON expression

Comment: @Ciccio please see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/764c7776-ca87-4246-a1ea-f6253efd498b/cronscheduled-webjob-not-working?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview#73262188-d93b-4d33-b780-ae2ea5eb4e2c) for the solution. I think you may miss one of these solutions.

Comment: I checked... I deployed again but now never run... I upload a hpto to ley you see the configuration

Comment: @Ciccio The image tells that job is deployed successfully. It will run. If you have any issues within your job. Then you have to see the webjobs logs

Comment: @Jayendran i do not have any issue. Logs do not show any error. The problem is the job runs continously even when should stop according to the CRON expression

Comment: @Ciccio From your updated image it is showing as `Ready` and type is `triggered`. How you are telling that it is running continuously?

Comment: @Jayendran I wrote it... "I deployed again but now never run... I upload a photo to ley you see the configuration"... It seems azure is ignoring my CRON expression... like it does what it wants... I do not understand why.. what's wrong